# What's the difference between the "fb:explicitly_shared" and "no_feed_story" parameters?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile, facebook-opengraph

I see mention of two different yet seemingly related parameters in the Facebook developer docs: `fb:explicitly_shared` and `no_feed_story`

The Explicity_shared param is documented here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/explicit_sharing/

And the "no_feed_story" param gets mentioned in a variety of places, including this blog post:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/

What is the difference between these parameters?

Comment: The first difference is, that their effects are _opposed_ to each other. no_feed_story should for example be used should it be necessary to publish multiple actions to get the right appearance for something concerning multiple “steps” that are undertaken on an object successively. explicitly_shared on the other hand is a means of “highlighting” actions that the user regards very important compared to other, minor ones.

Comment: IF they are opposed to each other, why would they be separate? For example, what does `fb:explicitly_shared=true` AND `no_feed_story=false` mean?

Comment: That the app developer is nuts.

Comment: My point is that I don't believe they are only opposed to each other, otherwise they wouldn't have them as distinct attributes.  This is why I'm asking the question on how it behaves since there are combinations of values that don't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that if you include `no_feed_story=true` it suppresses the activity from ticker and feed while if you set `fb:explicitly_shared=true` then your activity will be explicitly visible on your timeline as a post as well as within activity block opposed to if `fb:explicitly_shared=false` or not mentioned then the activity shows up only in activity block on your timeline. I don't see any correlation between two.